# What to call different education levels?

Tags: names

I've been always confused about the names of different education levels and how to use them, and which one is formal and which is not.

Can someone explain if it is master's or master? should I say M.Sc. or MSc? The same goes for bachelor. Is it bachelor's or bachelor? Is BSc./B.Sc./BSc formal in writing? what about the word "undergrad"?

Is it correct to say "I did my bachelor in business management in Canada"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology differs between different countries, and whether or not you use a full stop (period) in abbreviations is a matter of your choice of writing style. It's fine to use abbreviations for degree qualifications in all but the most formal contexts.

When you have obtained your degree (graduated) you are a Bachelor of Science. A degree at that level is a *bachelor's degree*. While studying for it you were an *undergraduate. Undergrad* is an informal abbreviation.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is it correct to say "while I was studying my bachelor's at university xyz in uwz"? (uwz being a country name)

Comment: You study _for_ a degree; it's a qualification, not a course. I'm not sure whether anyone would say _bachelor's_ for _bachelor's degree_. If so, it would be very informal.